# Having roundoff values for columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have summed the values and this below query sum the values and returns zero if there are no values.

How can I round off the values for these columns.

Here is my Query :

```
isnull(sum([Old_Values]),0) [Old Values],
[New_Value] = isnull(sum([Yearly_Value]-[Previous_Year_Value]),0)
```

Even this query I use for calculation and I need to round off the values

```
[Product_Price] = [Product_Profit]/4, 
[Product_Profit] = [ActualValue] * 0.75,
[GrossValue]
```

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[Product_Price] =Round([Product_Profit]/4,0), 
[Product_Profit] = Round([ActualValue] * 0.75,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
you could use FLOOR() or CEILING()
```

like this !

```
[Product_Price] = FLOOR([Product_Profit]/4), 
[Product_Profit] = FLOOR([ActualValue] * 0.75)
```

Comment: For better an we Round() should be used.

Comment: i guess nah.. it gives you a number with lot of zeroes ! `select round(10/2.3,0)` would give you `4.000000` wheres Floor gives you 4

Comment: Yes you are correct! But Floor() will give output of 5 for 4.2, which ideally should be 4. Same issue will be there with CEILING(). For issue of .0000000, we can do this Cast(Round([ActualValue] * 0.75,0) as Int).

Comment: @AK47 - yOUR SUGGESTION HELPED, BUT HOW CAN i APPLY FOR THIS ONE // [New_Value] = isnull(sum([Yearly_Value]-[Previous_Year_Value]),0)

Comment: Cast(Round(isnull(sum([Yearly_Value]-[Previous_Year_Value]),0),0) as Int)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROUND` ,like,

```
[Product_Price] =Round([Product_Profit]/4,2), 
[Product_Profit] = Round([ActualValue] * 0.75,2),
[GrossValue]
```